# Python class initialization - attributes memory

Tags: python, class, initialization

So I was writing a program in Python, which would take all my university classes (from csv) and print info about them. I've wrote a simple class `Subject` to manage everything better. In my uni there are classes in even weeks, odd weeks, and every-week classes, and I have lectures, exercises and laboratories. So my Subject class is like this:

```
class Subject:
    number = 0
    name = ""
    dummyData = []
    even = {}
    odd = {}
    all = {}
    type = ""
    def __init__(self, name, number, type):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.type = type
        self.info = str(number) + " " + name + " " + type
```

Previously I had all days written in `even`, `odd`, and `all` dicts, like this:

```
even = {"mon":"",
                "tue":"",
                "wed":"",
                "thu":"",
                "fri":"",
        }
```

So I could add all the classes hours to specific day key. But, there was a problem. For example lets say Programming lecture is subject 1 and Programming laboratories are subject 2. Subject 1 is on Monday at 9.15. Subject 2 is on Monday as well, but at 17.05. So I have a function, which would check if the subject is on even/odd week or it is every week. And then I would assign f.e 9.15 to `even["mon"]` on subject 1. Then I would go for subject 2, and tried to add 17.05 to `even["mon"]`. Every subject was an other Subject class object stored in a list. But there was a mistake. When I tried to add 17.05 to subject 2s `even["mon"]` it added it, okay, but then `even["mon"]` should `="17.05"`, but it was `="9.15/17.05"`. I was trying to figure out whats wrong, and I finally did, by changing my class from:

```
class Subject:
    number = 0
    name = ""
    dummyData = []
    even = {"mon":"",
                "tue":"",
                "wed":"",
                "thu":"",
                "fri":"",
        }
    ...etc...
    type = ""
    def __init__(self, name, number, type):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.type = type
        self.info = str(number) + " " + name + " " + type
```

to:

```
class Subject:
    number = 0
    name = ""
    dummyData = []
    even = {}
    odd = {}
    all = {}
    type = ""
    def __init__(self, name, number, type):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.type = type
        self.info = str(number) + " " + name + " " + type
        self.even = {"mon":"",
                "tue":"",
                "wed":"",
                "thu":"",
                "fri":"",
        }
```

+ odd and all. So why is Python like remembering whats been written into the first object attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the attributes inside the `__init__` method. Here's an example

```
class Subject:
    def __init__(self, name, number, type):
       self.number = number
       self.name = name
       self.dummyData = []
       self.even = {}
       self.odd = {}
       self.all = {}
       self.type = type
```

Declaring the variables inside the class declaration makes them "class" members and not instance members. Declaring them in the `__init__` method makes ensures a new instance of the members is created every time you create a new instance of the object.

Comment: So is it a bad practise, to make attributes above the init method?

Comment: Yes you don't need to do that, unless you want those variables shared across all instances of the class.